# Tableview Checkmark not display using iOS storyboard with objective C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I am trying to create `tableview` with `tableviewcell` and whenever user select the `tableviewcell` It should apply `checkmark`. My tableview and tableview cell everything I have created by `iOS` `storyboard`. Please help step by step how to solve my issue.

My Source:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellID";

    myTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[myTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *stringForCell;
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        stringForCell= [myData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1){
        stringForCell= [myData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+ [myData count]];
    }
    [cell.sec_Label setText:stringForCell];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code? Your implementation of tableview delegates, your custom cell, ...

Comment: check it above @JörnBuitink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way,first thing declare the variable's in header files

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellID";

     myTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

     if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[myTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     }

     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
     cell.tintColor =  [UIColor blackColor];

     NSString *stringForCell; // Mention in header file

     if (indexPath.section == 0) {
          stringForCell= [myData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     }
     else if (indexPath.section == 1){
          stringForCell= [myData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+ [myData count]];
     }
     [cell.sec_Label setText:stringForCell];
     return cell;
}
```

Comment: Its not working for me. Could you please mention the steps for storyboard @Mayank

Comment: put break point and check is this delegate calls ? @Apple_Ajay

Comment: Its came and executing exception at your line@Mayank Patel

Comment: `cell.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];` add this in this delegate method @Apple_Ajay

Comment: OMG I did mad mistakes...Its came now awesome! Thank you buddy@Mayank Patel

Comment: sure could you please modify your post whenever I slecte the cell Its should apply tick. suppose select another cell It should hide previous selectd and apply new one.@Maynak

Comment: @Apple_Ajay for this requirement you just need to manage cell clicks with `NSMutableArray` just try this ..for e.g in `didSelect` and `diddeselect` delegate method of UITableview you should do it

Answer (score 0):

write this in your tableview delegate function

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell ....//some creation

    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    //cell.accessView  don't set this, if set, use custom view. ignore accessoryType 


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: check if you have set accessoryView // if set, use custom view. ignore accessoryType. tracks if enabled can calls accessory action,@Apple_Ajay

Comment: sorry I cant get you! Please provide some codes!@Isdoy